# Gravitational field intensity of a ring

Tags: gravity, field-theory, calculus

I am given a ring of a certain radius and mass (assumed to be $R$ and $m$) which is kept in the $yz$-plane with it's axis along the $x$ axis and center at origin. At any point P on the $x$-axis the field intensity is given by

$$-Gm\frac{x}{(R^2+x^2)^{3/2}}$$

To obtain this answer I have integrated the component of intensity along $x$ with limits zero to the $x$ coordinate.

But this requires me to assume that all components perpendicular to $x$ will cancel each other (which I've made out) but also that all the $x$ components will add up (which I intuitively understood). For the latter what would be a mathematical proof?

Comment: You can write the field due to an element on the ring as a vector using unit vectors ($\hat i$, $\hat j$ and $\hat k$ in this case) and integrate that field. You would easily see that the integrals of the y and z component will get cancelled.

Comment: @FakeMod I kinda avoided that guessing it would go on too long but seems like that's the only way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

When you choose a small mass element $dm$ of the ring with radius $R$, then the gravitational field intensity due to $dm$ at any point $x$ is given by

$$
\vec{dI} = -G\frac{dm}{(R^2 + x^2)} \vec{r}
$$

where $\vec{r}$ is the unit vector along the line joining $x$ and $dm$.

Here, $\vec{dI}$ has two components: along $x$ axis and in $yz$ plane and they are given by:

$$
dI_x = -G\frac{xdm}{(R^2 + x^2)^{3/2}}
$$

$$
dI_{yz} = -G\frac{Rdm}{(R^2 + x^2)^{3/2}}
$$

Due to the symmetry of the ring, for any $yz$ component, you can find another $yz$ component with equal but opposite sign with the net effect being $0$. Mathematically, suppose that the angle made by $yz$ component with $y$ axis be $\theta$. Then the $y$ and $z$ component would be:

$$
dI_y = dI_{yz} \cos(\theta)
$$

$$
dI_z = dI_{yz} \sin(\theta)
$$

Because of symmetry $dI_{yz}$ is a constant. Suppose $dI_{yz} = A$ (Just to not make confuse with differential $d$). Now the net gravitational field intensity in $y$ direction and $z$ direction would be:

$$
I_y = \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} A \cos(\theta) d\theta = 0
$$

$$
I_z = \int \limits_{0}^{2\pi} A \sin(\theta) d\theta = 0
$$

Therefore the only thing you need to do now is to integrate the $dI_x$ component from $0$ to $m$ to find the total gravitational field intensity $\vec{I}$.

$$
\vec{I} = \int \limits_{0}^{m} -G\frac{xdm}{(R^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} \hat{x} = -Gm\frac{x}{(R^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} \hat{x}
$$